# Justification of dropping term in Hamiltonian and expectation Values

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, operators, hamiltonian-formalism

While reading Sakurai's Modern QM, I was stuck at the point where he explains the absorption and emission of light quanta in atoms. He proceeds with Hamiltonian:

$$H= p^2/2m + e\phi(x) -e/mc A\cdot p$$
where $p$ is momentum, $m$ is mass of an electron, $A$ is magnetic potential.

Next, he says to drop terms $p\cdot A$ and $|A|^2$ terms. He says that since $\nabla \cdot A=0$ the term can be dropped. However, I do not see any reason to drop $|A|^2$ term. Can anyone justify this?

My next question was about expectation value of $A\cdot p$. Sakurai writes:

$$\langle x|p\cdot A|y\rangle = -ih\nabla\cdot (A(x)\langle x| \rangle) = \langle x|A\cdot p| \rangle + \langle x| \rangle [-ih\nabla\cdot A(x)]$$

Can anyone explain how he manipulated the above equation to arrive at the result?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be justified to drop $ \left|A\right|^2$ if $A$ were small, so that $ \left|A\right|^2$ is negligible relative to $A$. This must be Sakurai's reason - the EM field is a small perturbation. Note, however, that one could also absorb the $ \left|A\right|^2$ term into a redefinition of $\phi$, so it doesn't qualitatively change the problem unless we're given a specific form for the potentials.

The relevance of $\nabla \cdot A=0$ is that $\left[\nabla ^\mu,A_\mu\right]=\nabla \cdot A$ so these operators commute in the Coulomb gauge. This means that upon expanding the $~\left(p-eA\right)^2$ term in the Hamiltonian it takes the form (5.7.1).